# Jquery filter class frustration

Tags: jquery

I'm losing my mind lol

I have this function:

```
 $(".tableIngredientsCut").filter(".notScalable").removeClass("notScalable").html("");
```

The console.log returns the correct set of objects but the .removeClass and .html functions don't actually do anything. If I remove the .filter it works fine (but on all objects).

What's happening?  Thanks.

Comment: working example please

Comment: Seems amazing... Would you please provide us with some jsfiddle? I tried your JS [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z8j47uLt/), it works fine. Do you run your JS after the page is fully loaded? E.g. in jQuery's document.ready?

Comment: That code works as it is, there must be something else you're not telling us :)

Answer (score 0):

I put this sample together that works:

```
<div class = 'aa'>
    <div class = 'cc'>
        sdf sdf sdf asdf
    </div>
    <div class = 'cc'>
        sdfsdfsdfsdf
    </div>
    <div class = 'cc'>
        sdfsdas dfasdfsdffsdfsdf
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("div").filter(".cc").removeClass("cc").html("")
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ht2wdkd/3/

Note that if you change the first selector to use the class name of the parent it will not work.

**Not** working JS:

```
$(".aa").filter(".cc").removeClass("cc").html("")
```

but if you use the class that you are filtering on it will work like this:

```
$(".cc").filter(".cc").removeClass("cc").html("")
```